# Is it possible the get the UID from within a systemd service file?

Tags: systemd

I have a service file which starts chromium on wayland:

```
[Unit]
Description=Launch Chromium
After=network.target weston.service
Requires=weston.service

[Service]
Type=simple
User=weston
Group=weston
Environment="XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000"
Environment="WAYLAND_DISPLAY=wayland-1"
ExecStart=/usr/bin/chromium
TimeoutSec=infinity

[Install]
WantedBy=graphical.target
```

Normally the weston user gets assigned the UID 1000 (I'm building a Yocto image so the UID could change potentially if there were changes in the image). It would be nice if there was a way to get the UID from within the systemd service file so that the setting for XDG_RUNTIME_DIR variable is always valid.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because IPTABLES SUPPORT IS OFF-TOPIC. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Support questions may be asked on https://superuser.com. Use this tag only for questions on programming with iptables. Questions about configuring iptables should be asked on Server Fault (https://serverfault.com/).

Comment: Take my upvote because I am facing the same problem when switching from Yocto 3.x to 4.x cause weston is now running in a seperate user. Thanks for the disucssion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set it to the first directory inside /run/user if you want to.

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/sh -c "XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=$(find /run/user/ -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 | head -n 1) /usr/bin/chromium"
```

But instead, you should be running the service as a user service of the user that logs in inside the graphical console.

Comment: I've used the id command to get the user id: ExecStart=/bin/sh -c 'XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/$(id -u weston) exec /usr/bin/chromium'